# Python line_profiler installation

Tags: python, installation, enthought, canopy

Hi I'm a newbie Python programmer.  I want line by line profiling and so have tried to install the line_profiler package. But it's not working.  Here is what I have done:

By the way I'm on Windows 8.1, 64 bit and I'm using Enthought Canopy.

I got the Windows install package from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler and installed it.

It says on the line_profiler site that a) I don't need to build it or need Cython, b) that I should do this:

> For IPython 0.11+, you can install it by editing the IPython
>   configuration file ~/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py to add
>   the 'line_profiler' item to the extensions list:
>
> c.TerminalIPythonApp.extensions = [
>       'line_profiler', ]

I restarted Canopy, no luck.  There should be a magic command %lprun.  It's not there.

I tried %load_ext line_profiler but got this message:

> C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\line_profiler.py
>   in ()
>        10 import sys
>        11 
>   ---> 12 from _line_profiler import LineProfiler as CLineProfiler
>        13 
>        14
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

Other things: I looked for a setup.py for this but couldn't find one for the line_profiler which seems to be installed in the C:\Users\OEM\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\Lib\site-packages folder.

So any help appreciated please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this question is quite old:

Nowadays, using `miniconda`/`Anaconda`, installation under Win 10 64-bit works like a charm; just do `conda install line_profiler` in the environment you are going to use. This will also add the `kernprof` command/script to your path in that environment.

Usage:

```
[add @profile decorators to the functions you want to profile]
kernprof -l ./your_script.py
python -m line_profiler ./your_script.py.lprof
```

Answer (score 14):

Im using Windows 10, 64 bit

1. You need go to unofficial binaries for python https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
2. Then press "Control+F" and type 'line_profiler',then choose it
   [Searching package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USlI1.png)
3. Im use Python 3.7 , Windows 10  64 bit. Then choose the last [Download your wheel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUhm7.jpg)
4. Open Command Prompt (Windows+R and type cmd)
5. Change direction to my downloads, where im download my file 'cd Downloads'
6. Than type this command
   C:/Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/Scripts/pip install "line_profiler-2.1.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"

[Output in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED2P5.png)

([Original source](https://pythonprogramming.net/using-pip-install-for-python-modules/))

Comment: Holy shit I asked this 5 years ago! Doesn't seem that long.  Thanks for taking the time to answer it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Well thanks for all the replies guys :)

Seriously though, I couldn't get this damn thing to install at all.

So I'm just using another profiler: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pprofile

It installed instantly, and I've been able to get it going first try.  Such a difference!

Comment: Thanks for that, but I just get "line_profiler-1.0b3-cp26-none-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform."

I tried both the 64 and 32 bit versions, same error.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same thing when building manually... it worked on one PC and not another...

The pre-built packages here worked: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#line_profiler